# How to disable WooCommerce product individual sale for perticular user?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

If an option "Sold Individually" is enabled for the WooCommerce product & I want to allow some users to purchase 'n' quantity of that product.

Eg.if an user is logged in

```
if(get_current_user_id()==20)
    {
    //Some code which will make product with individual sale available to buy in bulk. (Quantity field should be displayed on product page)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if(20 == $current_user->ID){

  add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_false' ); 

}
```

Please try this code. **Tested OK with WooCommerce 3.5.4**

Comment: The filter is getting applied but no quantity field was shown on product page.

Comment: @Hardik It's tested OK. I can see quantity box when adding this filter -- Please check if adding to cart twice is working or not

Comment: This filter works fine, adding cart twice works as well when filter is applied. Only When stock management is enabled for the product quanity field is not shown.

Comment: Hey,Thank you the code is working as expected the error was there in my custom code... Thanks again @Mujeebu

Comment: @Hardik No problem.